# How can I fix the following: 'ValueError: Cannot assign "2": "Actie.actie_gebruiker_id" must be a "Gebruiker" instance.'?

Tags: python, django

Here are the imports:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

This is the first class I did define. It is the status of the action (Actie) and it has a status-id and a status-name with a max_length attribute of 5 (todo, doing, done)

```
class Status(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    status_naam = models.CharField(max_length=5, default='todo')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + " - " + self.status_naam
```

This class Gebruiker (what means user) just has an id and a username

```
class Gebruiker(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    gebruiker_naam = models.CharField(max_length=5, default='Naamloze gebruiker')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + " - " + self.gebruiker_naam
```

This is the class Actie (Action or the action the user determines) which has an id, an action-name, a action-status which refers to the table Status here above, an action-publish-date, an ending-date (the deadline) and a user-id which refers to the table Gebruikers.

```
class Actie(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    actie_naam = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='-')
    actie_status_id = models.ForeignKey(Status, default=1)
    actie_aanmaakdatum = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    actie_einddatum = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1))
    actie_gebruiker_id = models.ForeignKey(Gebruiker, default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + " - " + self.actie_naam
```

When I code the following in the Python-shell after importing the class: a = Actie(actie_naam='Bake a cake', actie_gebruiker_id=2)

I get the following error: ValueError: Cannot assign "2": "Actie.actie_gebruiker_id" must be a "Gebruiker" instance.

I have the same problem with Actie.actie_status_id but what important is for now is the user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't give ForeignKey fields names ending with `_id`. The field itself gives access to the entire related object, it is not an ID. Django will suffix the underlying database field with `_id` anyway.

So your model should be:

```
class Actie(models.Model):
    ...
    actie_status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
    ...
    actie_gebruiker = models.ForeignKey(Gebruiker)
```

Now your existing code will work. You could of course make your code work by doing `a = Actie(actie_naam='Bake a cake', actie_gebruiker_id_id=2)` but that would be silly.

(For the sake of completeness, you could also do `gebruiker = Gebruiker.objects.get(id=2); a = Actie(actie_naam='Bake a cake', actie_gebruiker=gebruiker)`.)

(Also, there really isn't a good reason to give all your field names prefixes with the model name. That just adds verbosity for no benefit.)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. You just solved my problem I was dealing with the whole time..